# Web Api Model is returning null as posting from Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, json.net, webapi

1) Web Api Controller.

```
    [Route("InsertRecipes")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostRecipes(Recipes model)
        {
            db.Recipes.Add(recipes);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
            return message;
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = recipes.ID }, recipes);
        }
```

2) Recipes.cs (Model class`enter code here`

```
[Table("tbl_Recipes")]
public class Recipes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public Ingredients Ingredients;

}
```

3) In Angular calling the POST method

```
storeRecipes(){
        const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
        this.http.post('http://localhost:62286/Api/Recipes/InsertRecipes',recipes).pipe()
                .subscribe(response =>{
                    console.log(response);
                });
    }
```

4) This the JSON receiving from Angular

```
 {
    "name": "Fish Curry",
    "description": "Fish Curry - taste really awesome",
    "imagePath": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_1600/recipes/fish_curry_09718_16x9.jpg",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "Green Chilli",
        "amount": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "Fish",
        "amount": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Ginger Galic Paste",
        "amount": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Onion",
        "amount": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Tomato",
        "amount": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Master",
        "amount": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Masala",
        "amount": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

All the time while Posting from angular , I am receiving null in the model of that controller.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the null?  The recipeService.getRecipes() is returning the JSON listed in 4) above?  Are you seeing null in the console.log(response)?

Comment: No in the web Api model "public HttpResponseMessage PostRecipes(Recipes model)"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FromBody` and `[HttpPost]`. you are putting the model (here is recipes) in the body of your http request, that's why you should receive it from body .

modify your `PostRecipes` in web api  like the following :

```
  [Route("InsertRecipes")]
  [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostRecipes([FromBody]Recipes model)
        {
            db.Recipes.Add(recipes);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
            return message;
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = recipes.ID }, recipes);
        }
```

then in your angular service :

```
public storeRecipes() {
    // make sure that recipes is not null ....
    const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
    this.http.post('http://localhost:62286/Api/Recipes/InsertRecipes', recipes, this.setHttpHeader()).pipe()
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
private setHttpHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Then also I am getting null in the model. Please find the code for getting the recipes from different service

Comment: getRecipes(){
        return this.recipes.slice();
    }

Comment: Are  you sure that you have data in `const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();`

Comment: private recipes:Recipe[]= [
        new Recipe(
            'Fish Curry',
            'Fish Curry - taste really awesome',
            'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_1600/recipes/fish_curry_09718_16x9.jpg',
            [
                new Ingredient ('Green Chilli', 5),
                new Ingredient ('Fish',1),
                new Ingredient ('Ginger Galic Paste',1),
                new Ingredient ('Onion',2),
                new Ingredient ('Tomato',2),
                new Ingredient ('Master', 3),
                ....
            ])
      ];

Comment: which I receive via getRecipes(){ return this.recipes.slice(); }

Answer (score 0):

You missed `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]`, do it as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("InsertRecipes")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostRecipes([FromBody] Recipes model)
        {
            db.Recipes.Add(recipes);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
            return message;
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = recipes.ID }, recipes);
        }
```